How to Fix Poor Mobile LCP Performance on WooCommerce Site with Sage, Tailwind CSS, and LiteSpeed Cache?
I’ve built an eCommerce website using WooCommerce. For the theme, I’m using the Sage WordPress starter theme, along with Tailwind CSS and Laravel Blade. To handle page optimization, I’m relying on LiteSpeed Cache Plugin.
I’ve been running tests using PageSpeed Insights and successfully improved the Largest Contentful Paint (LCP) for the desktop version, achieving solid overall performance. However, the mobile performance remains poor, particularly for LCP, which is dragging down the overall score.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Optimized images
Minified and combined CSS/JavaScript files
Lazy-loaded images

These steps helped for desktop, but I’m still struggling with mobile performance. What additional strategies or adjustments can I make to optimize mobile LCP, especially with my setup involving WooCommerce, Tailwind CSS, and Sage? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Website Dev Environment with versions:

Sage(WordPress starter theme by roots.io): 9.0.9
WordPress: 6.6.2
Woocommerce: 9.3.3

PageSpeed Insights Result: https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-ubnaturals-com-product-black-thunder-active-plus/42brjx8zgr?form_factor=mobile
Page I am trying to optimise: https://www.ubnaturals.com/product/black-thunder-active-plus/

Thanks!
